# format a string using .format() to convert a float into dollars and cents left justified in python

Tags: python, string-formatting, string.format

I am trying to use `.format()` to convert a float into a dollar amount. I have accomplished that task, however, I have a major problem. I get empty spaces in between the dollar sign and the value. Is there a way for me to have the field length (width of the field) constant and have the "$" next to the number, regardless of the numbers length?

This is what I have tried:

[Screenshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po4Ly.png)

```
money = 1243432.6
```

1. `'${:>,.2f}'.format(money)`
   Output: `'$1,243,432.60'`
2. `'${:>10,.2f}'.format(money)`
   Output:`'$         1,243,432.60'`
3. `'${:>20,.2f}'.format(money)`
   Output:`'$         1,243,432.60'`

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: *Aside*: `float()` is often a poor choice for tracking money. Consider keeping track of total cents and dividing by 100 or maybe using `decimal.Decimal()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `str.format()` method as below:

```
float_ = 1976.25
print('${:.2f}'.format(float_))
```

The parameter `.2f` forces format method to show only two decimals after the point.

You could show the commas representing thousands with a little change:

```
print('${:,.2f}'.format(float_))
```

Comment: @pault Edited out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that you may find helpful.

```
amounts = [1.234, 20.3, 100.19999]
for a in amounts:
    print("${:0.2f}".format(a))
#$1.23
#$20.30
#$100.20
```

More information on the format specification can be found [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).